# Switch TabActivity inside of an activity Android

Tags: android, tabactivity, tabwidget

I am trying to change may current Tab. I search for fitting problems but it not solved my own one.
I have a Tab activity like this

```
<!-- language: java -->   
public class myTabActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final TabHost mtabHost = getTabHost();
    int tabnum = getIntent().getIntExtra("currenttab", 0);


    mtabHost.addTab(mtabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
            .setIndicator("firsttab")
                .setContent(new Intent(this, tabA.class)));
    mtabHost.addTab(mtabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
            .setIndicator("secondtab")
                .setContent(new Intent(this, tabB.class)));
     setCurrentTab(tabnum);
}
private boolean setCurrentTab(int i) {
    if (getParent() instanceof SimpleSundayScoutUIActivity) {
        ((SimpleSundayScoutUIActivity) getParent()).getTabHost().setCurrentTab(i);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and an activity tabA like this

```
public class text extends Activity {
myTabActivity mA = (myTabActivity) this.getParent();
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);
    Button startbutton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchbutton);
    startbutton.setOnClickListener(mNewListener);
}
private OnClickListener mNewListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),SimpleSundayScoutUIActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("currenttab", 1);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

means what i want to do is klick on the Button of tabA and then the tab widget should show me tabB but it doesnt work like this

any suggestions? 
sry am not really fit in quoting hope it is readable

thanks for help 
patrick

**edit**

mokup for what i want to do http://tinypic.com/r/f6uyq/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edited:*

Tab class:

```
public class myTabActivity extends TabActivity {
public static TabHost mtabHost; // change to public static
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     mtabHost = getTabHost();
    int tabnum = getIntent().getIntExtra("currenttab", 0);


    mtabHost.addTab(mtabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
            .setIndicator("firsttab")
                .setContent(new Intent(this, tabA.class)));
    mtabHost.addTab(mtabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
            .setIndicator("secondtab")
                .setContent(new Intent(this, tabB.class)));
     setCurrentTab(tabnum);
}
private boolean setCurrentTab(int i) {
    if (getParent() instanceof SimpleSundayScoutUIActivity) {
        ((SimpleSundayScoutUIActivity) getParent()).getTabHost().setCurrentTab(i);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Button Class:

```
public class text extends Activity {
myTabActivity mA = (myTabActivity) this.getParent();
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);
    Button startbutton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchbutton);
    startbutton.setOnClickListener(mNewListener);
}
private OnClickListener mNewListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
     myTabActivity.mtabHost.setCurrentTab(1); //Remove .this 

    }
};
```

Comment: hey :) .. sry this dont solve my problem .. i know this example i dont want to set my tab all the time if i klick on the button of one tab i want to activate an other tab of my tab widget like this http://tinypic.com/r/f6uyq/5

Comment: :) thx .. but in my class tabA i dont have "mtabHost" how can i acces it .. i tryed to make mytabActivity as singelton and get in tabA the instance of myTabActivity .. but it also dont work how could i set the current tab in an activity

Comment: thx for ur fast answers .. i did what u say but now i get this error "No enclosing instance of the type SimpleSundayScoutUIActivity is accessible in scope"  in the line "myTabActivity.this.mtabHost.setCurrentTab(1);" .. thx for answering this fast :)
.. how could i solve this ;)

Comment: You're welcome dude ;-) , Check my edits once again , Should be work now :-D

Comment: hey :) .. thx my i found the failure but u also changed it .. now it works .. much thx :)